# ASP Huge vertical space in table field containing an asp-dropdownlist inside of formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html-table, formview

I have a table nested inside of a formview. Most fields are fine, but any containing a dropdownlist will have a huge vertical space above it, and the actual dropdown control is ignoring the stylesheet and is sticking to the bottom left of the field. Also, this isn't the style sheet's doing, as i have completely disabled my site.css and the problem is still occurring. Any advice?

Comment: The markup and the css are conspicuously missing from your question.

Comment: If you mean the code itself, it's developed on a closed network, no way to really pull the code off easily. I know it's not the CSS, i disabled it entirely and still have the problem.

Comment: Surely there's at least a bit of markup that you can cut'n'paste from your "view source", no? Without anything, nobody is going to guess at a solution.